# iOS: Display Google Search Results in UIWebView without API

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app where a user can select a keyword, and the app will display search results from Google via an in-app `UIWebView`.

e.g. A user selects `my term name`, I construct this URL: `https://www.google.com/search?q=my+term+name`, and open that URL in a `UIWebView`.

Is this against Google's terms of service? Do I need to include any sort of authentication credentials in the URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just displaying a google web page, then that's fine.  All you've done is construct a URL and display the results.  If you were parsing / scraping the results, then you'd have a legal issue.  If it were a problem services such as lmgtfy would not be legal.

Comment: When you say parsing, what if I use Google Custom Search and display the images from Google Custom Search without Google branding, is that legal or illegal? Thanks for the clarification in advance. @matt

Comment: You'd need to clarify with Google I expect.  If you didn't have any Google branding at all - I expect they'd have an issue. Remember they make money from advertising, they aren't going to be happy about giving away their services for free.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.... Try this:

```
     Google Search = http://google.com/search?q=ios
```

For other search engines:

1. Yahoo Search = http://search.yahoo.com/?q=ios
2. Bing Search = http://www.bing.com/search?q=ios
3. Ask Search = http://www.ask.com/web?q=ios

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=ios >> this loads perfectly fine in iPad and Mac but in iPhone it displays google without text iOS in search bar. Any suggestion what could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Scrapping results directly from goog html is a violation of their TOS.

Clause 5.3 Google TOS:

"You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)..."

Comment: I don't think any of that applies here.

Comment: This isn't scraping. It's a valid URL & no authentication is required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
-(void)recivedRequest {

    //load the request to a web view
    [webView loadRequest:[NSUrlConnection connectionWithURL:[URL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=my+term+name"]]]];
```

Or if you want to create a string before loading the request, you can do that:

```
-(void)recivedRequest {

    //create a NSString with the keyword
    NSString *keyWord = @"my+term+name";

    //load the request to a web view
    [webView loadRequest:[NSUrlRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@", keyWord]]]];
```

Comment: webView loads URLRequests . here you mentioned urlconnection. I have edited it though.

Answer (score 0):

No, It does not requires any authentication credentials or some certificate to view the Google links in your ios devices.

I you think it will have any problems then you can make multiple webpages and use them in iOS using  phoneGap.